# How To Map the Color of a Curve to A Scalar Value in a Given Range

Tags: python, plot, iteration, colormap

I am attempting to plot 175 curves with a for loop, and coloring each curve based on a scalar value associated with each of the curves.

I've been trying to use matplotlib.colors, and matplotlib.cm to do this, but the color outputs I'm getting are not correct. For reference, I am manipulating the data using pandas instead of numpy.

```
Map = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = min(SPARC.SBeff), vmax = 
max(SPARC.SBeff), clip=True)
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=Map,cmap='RdYlGn')

plt.figure(4)
for i in range(1,175):
    plt.plot(np.log(MM[MM.Name == GalaxyNames[i]].Rad), \
    np.log(MM[MM.Name == GalaxyNames[i]].Vobs),\
    mapper.to_rgba(SPARC[SPARC.Name == GalaxyNames[i]].SBeff[0])
```

I would like each of the curves to have color based on a scalar value, for which I have minimum and maximum values.

Comment: @alr23, keep in mind that `range(1, 175)` will generate numbers from 1 up to 174, 175 will not be included.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes, thank you. My apologies, I know. even for range(0,175) I am still not getting the results I need.